# Is "We are looking forward to hear from you." correct?

Tags: infinitives

"We are looking forward to hearing from you." treats "to" as a particle used with "are looking forward" (V) and "hearing from you" (NP) to form the verb phrase "are looking forward to hearing from you",

and "We are looking forward to hear from you." treats "to" as a particle used with "hear from you" (VP) to form an infinitive verb phrase "to hear from you".

Can "look forward" take an infinitive verb phrase to form the latter sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Look forward to” is a phrasal verb, and the preposition “to” is an integral part of the verb. So, to use a to-infinitive, you would have to say

> I am looking forward to to see her

**WHICH IS NOT IDIOMATIC**.

You cannot idiomatically use a to-infinitive as a complement to phrasal verbs ending with “to.”

Answer (score 0):

The usual form is "*looking forward to hearing from  you*".

[image]

> (**OALD,  2005 edition**) **look  forward  to** [+ ing]

Comment: so can "look forward" take an infinitive verb phrase?